# Estoy trayendo unos datos de una tabla sql y cuando lee el campo de fecha me tira el error System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Estoy haciendo una consulta a unas tablas sql. La consulta sale bien en sql, solo que al llevarla a un stored procedure y luego obtenerla desde c# me tira el error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` en el campo de *Fecha_Laquiaca*.

Ahí coloco el código:

```
public List<VentaSucursalViewModel> listarArticulos()
        {
            var fechaFiltro = "2023-09-20";
            var fechaFiltro2 = "2023-09-21";
            var fechaInicio = new DateTime();
            var fechaFin = new DateTime();
            fechaInicio = DateTime.Parse(fechaFiltro);
            fechaFin = DateTime.Parse(fechaFiltro2);
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conexion"));
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = "sp_MovimientoMercaderia_VentasSucursales_Fecha";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = conexion;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaInicio", fechaInicio);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaFin", fechaFin);
            conexion.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            List<VentaSucursalViewModel> listaVendidos = new List<VentaSucursalViewModel>();
            while (reader.Read() == true)
            {
                VentaSucursalViewModel venta = new VentaSucursalViewModel();
                venta.idArticulo = Convert.ToInt32(reader["IdArticulo"]);
                venta.nombreArticulo = Convert.ToString(reader["nombre"]);
               
                if (reader["Fecha_Laquiaca"] != DBNull.Value) //En esta linea me tira el error
                {
                    venta.fechaVentaLaQuiaca = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Fecha_Laquiaca"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    venta.fechaVentaLaQuiaca = null;
                }

                if (reader["Fecha_AbraPampa"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    venta.fechaVentaAbraPampa = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Fecha_AbraPampa"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    venta.fechaVentaAbraPampa = null;
                }
                listaVendidos.Add(venta);
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return listaVendidos;
        }
```

Quisiera saber cómo solucionarlo. En la definición de la base de datos, los campos están declarados como `DateTime`.

El código del stored procedure es este:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_MovimientoMercaderia_VentasSucursales_Fecha]
    @fechaInicio datetime,
    @fechaFin datetime

AS
select  art.idArticulo, art.nombre, suc_LQ.stock_Vendido as stock_VendidoLaQuiaca, suc_AP.stock_Vendido as stock_VendidoAbraPampa,  suc_LQ.fecha_hora as FechaLaquiaca, suc_AP.fecha_hora as FechaAbraPampa from
    (select * from Movimiento_Mercaderia where idTipo_Sucursal=2 and fecha_hora>=@fechaInicio and fecha_hora<@fechaFin) as suc_LQ
full join
    (select * from Movimiento_Mercaderia where idTipo_Sucursal=3 and fecha_hora>=@fechaInicio and fecha_hora<@fechaFin) as suc_AP
on suc_LQ.idArticulo=suc_AP.idArticulo
join 
    Articulo as art on art.idArticulo = suc_AP.idArticulo or art.idArticulo = suc_LQ.idArticulo
```

Answer (score -1):

Recibes `IndexOutOfRangeException` porque el campo `Fecha_Laquiaca` no existe en el `SqlDataReader reader`, el nombre del campo, según el procedimiento es `FechaLaquiaca`.

En mi opinión `IndexOutOfRangeException` es confuso en este caso, probalemente sería más claro que el error fuera `KeyNotFoundException`

Comment: Corríjame si me equivoco pero `KeyNotFoundException` tendría sentido si el `SqlDataReader` fuese un `Dictionary<string,object>`, pero no es el caso. Es una abstracción de un dataset con filas y columnas. `IndexOutOfRangeException` aunque no es perfecto, es adecuado, a menos que quieras implementar tu propio `ColumnNameNotFoundException`

Comment: @Arriel, en mi opinión el data reader funciona como un diccionario donde obtienes el valor de un campo por la clave que es el nombre del campo. Si el nombre del campo no existe lo que no existe es la clave, no el índice como parece indicar IndexOutOfRangeException